# Take space separated input having different data types

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am trying to input 4 values into 4 variables that are separated by space in the user input.

For example :

**a b 2 5**

The first values two are characters, while the other 2 values are of int datatype.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, use raw_input in python 2 (and input in python 3):

```
>>> inp = raw_input("Enter space separated values of form 'a b 2 5' \n")
Enter space separated values of form 'a b 2 5' 
a b 2 5
>>> vars = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in inp.split()]
>>> vars
['a', 'b', 2, 5]
```

Basically, you can have multiple space separated values in the same input, and you can split them later.